# how to make a JSON for putting src and dest addresses in it and we can call that JSON in our grunt.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs

I am working on `grunt` for making building tool, till now I was putting `src` and `dest` addresses directly in my grunt.js file but in this case if I want to change my dest I have to change in every task of file which is not a good practice.for example if my grunt.js file have following task:

```
concat: {
  js: {
    src: 'src/js/*.js',
    dest: 'dest/js/concat.js'
  },
  css: {
    src: 'src/css/*.css',
    dest: 'dest/css/concat.css'
  }
},
min: {
  js: {
    src: 'dest/js/concat.js',
    dest: 'dest/js/concat.min.js'
  }
},
```

here if I change my address than i have to change in every place!!!
I want a `JSON` file in which I can declare src and dest and call in my grunt.js file. How can we do that???

Comment: That's my grunt.js file, I am asking for creating a JSON for src and dest addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to `package.json` to declare metadata, for example

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "meta":{
     "src":"someSrcFolder",
     "dest":"someDestFolder"
   },
 ....
}
```

Then in your `Gruntfile.js`, you could read those properties like this

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: '<json:package.json>',
  concat: {
    js: {
      src: '<%= pkg.meta.src %>/js/*.js',
      dest: '<%= pkg.meta.dest %>/js/concat.js'
    },
    css: {
      src: '<%= pkg.meta.src %>/css/*.css',
      dest: '<%= pkg.meta.dest %>/css/concat.css'
    }
  }
});
```

The important bits are `pkg:<json:package.json>` which loads the json file into memory and the underscore template interpolations `<%= pkg.meta.src %>` which evaluate to the contents of the `meta` property added to the json file.

Keep in mind that the **Gruntfile** is just a JavaScript file so you could also have an object with references to paths and then interpolate them into your tasks.

Answer (score 1):

This changed in Grunt.js 0.4.0.

You would now use: `pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')`